# Separate Environments for each emacsclient

Tags: emacsclient, server, environment

I have a single emacs server that I use for all of my work. It is located on a machine that I ssh into from every location.

My 'browse-url is set to run a bash script that ssh's into the machine I am running emacsclient on and opens Chrome. However, this only works if I use emacs from one machine.

I need a method for my emacs server to change its behavior based on the emacs client (whether it is an environmental variable, a variable that gives the hostname of the client, or anything else). I can't seem to find anything right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to look at the `environment` frame parameter, which the server.el code sets up whenever a frame is created for a particular client:

```
(frame-parameter nil 'environment)
```

This should then hold a list of strings, where some of those strings will be like "SSH_CLIENT=IP PORT1 PORT2".

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.